# Error while cast data from nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, type-conversion

I have `table1` with two columns:

- `col1 - nvarchar(510)`
- `col2 - nvarchar(510)`

I want to take all the values from `table1` and put it to `table2` where data type is different:

- `col1_A - numeric(22,10)`
- `col2_A - int`

I'm doing like:

```
insert into table2 
    select cast(col1 as numeric), cast(col2 as int)
```

but I'm getting error:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: You probably have a character in one of the rows inin table1.col1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you **Eric** for help to find wrong recrods!
I did case as below:

```
case
 when [col1] LIKE '%,%' then REPLACE([col1]),',','')
else  CAST([col1] as Numeric)
end
```

and it's working!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a character in `table1.col1`. Also, it's important to point out that `table1.col1` is `nvarchar(510)` but `if len(table1.col1) > 11` you are going to get an **Arithmetic overflow error**.

```
declare @char nvarchar(510)
set @char = '123456789101'
--set @char = '1234567891011'   --will cause an arithmetic overflow error since you are using numeric(22,10)
--set @char = '123abc456'       --will cause Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

declare @num numeric(22,10)
set @num = cast(@char as numeric(22,10))

select @num
```

Comment: scsimon -> what type is good to keep values like: "10.20", "8.6", "124.8743", "10456.73" ??

Comment: decimal and numeric are fine, and what you need, you just have to account for the precision and total length to avoid arithmetic overflow. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.

Answer (score 1):

It means you need to sanitize your data. Find which values are causing the issue and then manually correct them first or exclude them. To find which values are not numeric use the [`ISNUMERIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function.

```
select col1 
from yourtable 
where ISNUMERIC(col1) = 0
```

Comment: This will work unless the problem is that it's a faulty decimal delimiter. If problem isn't found with this you could add < OR col1 LIKE '%,%' > at the end (without < >).

Comment: Igor -> it return 0 rows

Comment: Eric -> I got couple of rows, what it's mean?

Comment: @4est - you should correct those found records, if you are not sure if they can be converted or not try it for just that value or post the values back in your question.

Comment: just posted how I did and now it's fine :)